# wso2 identity server integration with external ldap

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am very new to wso2. I try to integrate wso2 identity server 5.0 with an external ldap. I configured it according to this : https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+a+Read-only+LDAP+User+Store
At the end of the link, it says that try to sign in with admin user but how can I authenticate an another user which is available in LDAP? Is it possible to login to the identity server with another ldap user (other than admin).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

according the configuration how it is described, a new user 'admin' with 'admin' role is added after startup. I assume you want to log on another user. You should be able to authenticate other users as well for other service providers (applications), but not in the management console. For that the admin role is required.

What you can try is to use the 'dashboard' application ( https://your-is-server-hostname:9443/dashboard/ )

Have fun
         g.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Gabriel. Actually i am looking for an open-source identity&access management solution which supports LDAP integration in order to see if it is feasible to replace it with Apache Shiro.

Comment: WSO2 IS is a product / server. It provides identity management, identity federation and attribute based authorization (XACML). If you need only to authenticate users using LDAP, you can be good with JAAS or spring-security as well. Apache Shiro seems to be a framework (set of APIs). To build security features in your application, but Shiro doesn't provide identity management or federation itself. They are on the completely different level of usablity.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are configuring a read-only LDAP as the primary user store,
The user that should have admin permissions is required to be stored in the user store when you start the system for the first time. After that you have to give the login permission for all users in the LDAP user store. Login permission defined under admin permissions, which allows users to login to the management console.

1. Configure----->Users and Roles----->Roles----->Select "Permissions" of "Internal/everyone" or "Internal/your configured application" that you would like to give the permission.
2. Select "Login".
3. Update.

For the more details you can refer [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Role-based+Permissions